# Add duplicates to a set or check if the elements exists then add

Tags: python, duplicates, set

Using sets in python, I want to add many items to my set, some of which probably already exist in that set.

Is it faster to add items to a set without checking if it's already there, or is it faster to check if each item exists in the set already and only add if it isn't there?

Comment: Asymptotically speaking both would take `O(n)` time for build the set. May be time both of them. I would use `set(iterable)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's faster to add without checking. Every time you add an item to a set it needs to check that the item isn't there - Checking before is not saving you any time if the item is there, but it is wasting time if it isn't there as it will be checked twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add duplicates to a set so there is no point in checking. See Python's documentation for sets:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries. You can try to add a duplicate and it won't actually add it to the set. It will just ignore it.

```
p = set([2,3,4,5])

p.add(99) # try to add 99 to existing set
print p
    result: set([99, 2, 3, 4, 5])
p.add(99) # try to add 99 again. Notice the set doesn't change
print p
    result: set([99, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check!

That's the thing with sets, they don't have duplicates. Look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), they clearly state that sets don't have duplicates. If a duplicate is attempted to be added to the set, the compiler "ignores it" and passes on to the next piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if you have a new item for your list you could use this code:

```
yourlist=[1,2,3,4,5] #This is only needed if you are checking for duplicate numbers
newitem=2
new=1
for i in range(len(yourlist)):
    if yourlist[i]==newitem:
    new=0
if new==1:
    yourlist.append(newitem)
print(yourlist)
```

Hope this helps!